# "Fx" button to setup conditional page navigation not available on Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dashboard

I am trying to create a dropdown menu and a button to navigate across multiple pages in my Power Bi project.

I am following this guide:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kaUnBXvvGo&t=6s

However, when you have to define the conditional destination by clicking on the "Fx" button, I can't find this button.

This is what I should see according to the tutorial:

[image]

This is what I see... there is not "Fx" button to define a conditional destination.

However, I can define a conditional tooltip (Descrizione comando) since if I hoover next to the text "Descrizione Comando" three dots appear and let me define the conditional tooltip. That's not happening for "Destination".

[image]

Comment: Wondering the same thing. It seems to be removed in the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

I also can't find a way to achieve this in PowerBI Desktop, but I was able to do this through PowerBI services.

Step 1: Upload your report with the button you want to set conditionally to PBI services if you haven't done so yet.

Step 2: Open the report in the browser

Step 3: Click the edit button in the top options
[image: Edit button]

Step 4: Select you button, you'll see you'll be able to set the destination conditionally

Step 5: Save the report

Step 6: Download the PBIX again

After this just don't touch the destination of the button.
You can copy-paste in your project.